# how to call external javascript method in the page load of the user control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a scenario where i have a user control within a page which consists of core asp.net logic external javascript and UI and the page is just an container for this user control.
Now i need to inject a javascript at page load of the user control by calling a javascript function of the external javascript file but its not working.Any Help?

In Page_Load

```
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptKey",      "TC.Report.OnSelectedReportChange('" + noParameterReports + "');");

        ddlReport.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return  TC.Report.OnSelectedReportChange('" + noParameterReports + "');");
```

In external javascript

```
      OnSelectedReportChange: function (noParameterReports) {
            var noParameterReport = noParameterReports.split("|");
            var enableParameters = "true";
            var pageName = TC.Report.getPageName(window.location.href);
            for (i = 0; i < noParameterReport.length; i++) {
                if ($("select[id$=ddlReport]").val() == noParameterReport[i]) {
                    if (pageName == "AGIReports") {
                        $('.officeTextBox').children().attr('disabled', true);
                        $('.dropDownTEMethod').children().attr('disabled', true);
                    } else {
                        $("select[id$=ddlOpCo]").disabled = true;
                        $("select[id$=ddlWeekEndingDate]").disabled = true;
                    }

                    enableParameters = "false";
                }
            }
            if (enableParameters == "true") {
                if (pageName == "AGIReports") {
                    $('.officeTextBox').children().attr('disabled', false);
                    $('.dropDownTEMethod').children().attr('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $("select[id$=ddlOpCo]").disabled = false;
                    $("select[id$=ddlWeekEndingDate]").disabled = false;
                }

            }
        }
```

I have a few observation to this..firstly the registerstartup script executed first before the user control is loaded so it throws an error TC is undefined which is rightly so as the external java script is reference in user control only but i am calling this method from user control's page load.

Secondly i tried to add the register startup script on prerender event after adding ethe javascript file reference in the page but then it says object require when ddlreport object references in the javascript method..page render guarantees that controls are loaded and available

Comment: what about the onload javascript code to jQuery(document).ready() on client side

Comment: Is there a way to pass parameter with a value from code behind using regitster startup script.I guess ready method will execute prior to the value being assign to my parameter and will be null. i am setting this parameter in page load and i need to pass it to the external javascript function

Comment: no.. document.ready will happen after all your page HTML is loaded in the browser, you could pass values from codebehind in asp:hidden field  to javascript

Comment: You can also set the data attributes on an element to pass values to js

Comment: I tried using hidden field to set the parameter at the page load  which would than be used inside the documet.ready function to pass its value to the external javascript method but i am getting undefined value of the hidden field even though the value rightly set in the page load method